# how to update a dropdown using ajax in razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

this is my drop down :`@Html.EditorFor(m => m.CustomerBasicInfo.CheckUpDR)`
i want it to be updated either whenever it's been clicked or when a reload button hit. i mean i wonder if i can reload it even by clicking on it but if its not possible i want it to reload by hitting reload button.
for example here i put a button and it call an ajax function:

```
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-11">
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.CustomerBasicInfo.CheckUpDR) 
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <a href="#" class="btn" sdata-placement="top" onclick="ReloadDropDown()">
                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and here is the ajax function :

```
 function ReloadDropDown() {
    debugger;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '@Url.Action("FillCheckDrDropDown", "CustomerInfoControler")',
        data: { },
        success: function (res) {
            $("#CheckUpDR").value(res);
            alert('Successfully called');
        },
        error: function (jqxhr, status, exception) {
            alert('Exception:', exception);
        }
    });

}
```

and here is the controller for loading data:

```
 public JsonResult FillCheckDrDropDown()
    {
        var model = _service.GetCheckUpDRLists();
        return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

with considering that i'm very new to ajax would you pleas help me where i'm going wrong that my ajax function doesn't work and what i can do to update the drop down.thank you.

Comment: remove `debugger;`

Comment: remove debugger and make selector empty before binding data